# Ruby on rails application on App42 PaaS

Tags: paas

I deployed my Ruby on Rails application on App42 PaaS. After doing setupInfra.  I created binary of my app and deployed it. it's working fine as expected.Now i wanted to access log of my app.Could any one please help me to get logs of my app?

Comment: Unfortunately  can't add the tag for app42Paas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your application log using [App42 PaaS Management Console](https://paashq.shephertz.com/) As well [App42 Client](https://rubygems.org/gems/app42) (a command line tool).

App42 client:

```
app42 logs --app APP NAME
```

App42 PaaS Management Console:

Once you logged in, On app list you will find app log link to visit application logs.

Comment: Thanks for explaination